# SHAP values for Prophet / time series data

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet, shap, dalex

I would like to utilize shap values for multivariate time series data and models like prophet.

```
from prophet import Prophet
ph = Prophet()

for column in time_series_df.drop(columns = ['y', 'ds'], inplace = False).columns:
    ph.add_regressor(column, standardize='auto', mode = 'additive')
ph.add_country_holidays('US')

ph.fit(time_series_df)
```

I now want to, utilize dalex (or shap) to get the shape values

```
import dalex
def predict_function(model, data):
    return model.predict(data)['yhat'].to_numpy()

dalex_ex = dalex.Explainer(ph, ph_train, label = 'y', predict_function = predict_function)
```

But it throws the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the
> inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
> the casting rule ''safe''

Is there a way how to handel data-time data better for those kind of algorithms?

Comment: This won't anwser your question, but you can check regressor "importance" with coef. 
 regressor_coefficients(model), more info can be found on prophet github page.

Comment: `Explainer` has pretty limited number of models it can explain. Use `KernelExplainer` instead.

Comment: The Problem stays the same. I think the issue is that shap can not handle datetimevalues. This is were I am trying to find a solution for.

Comment: @Bara the undelying model treats datetimes like `<time_unit>_since_arbitrary_date` -- like an integer.  Perhaps the solution involves using the `KernelExplainer` and some sort of two-way conversion from datetime to integer before feeding to SHAP.